# Sending a message programmatically with Odoo 8.0

Tags: python, odoo-8

I'm trying to send a custom message notification to user that signup via the signup page.  I plan to place that code just after the user as been created. Here's the controller extending the AuthSignHome controller:

```
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AuthSignupHome(openerp.addons.web.controllers.main.Home):

    def do_signup(self, qcontext):
            """ Shared helper that creates a res.partner out of a token """
            values = dict((key, qcontext.get(key)) for key in ('login', 'name', 'password', 'document_attestation'))
            assert any([k for k in values.values()]), "Le formulaire n'est pas correctement remplis."
            assert values.get('password') == qcontext.get('confirm_password'), "Les mot de passe ne concorde pas."
            self._signup_with_values(qcontext.get('token'), values)

            // SEND GREETING MESSAGE

            request.cr.commit()
```

How can it be done?